# Keep session after browser restart java

Tags: java, session, servlets, web-applications

I'm working on a small project with java servlets/jstl

I've created a login with a session and I want the browser to keep that session even after a browserrestart.

I've written this code:

```
HttpSession session=request.getSession();
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(604800);
session.setAttribute("loggedOnUser", true);
```

I've set the session timeout to a week. But whenever I close the browser and reopen it I need to login again. When I look at the cookies of my browser, the cookie that contains the sessionId still expires when the browser closes. I thought "setMaxInactiveInterval" would change that to one week. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: have you tried cookie.setMaxAge!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest setting the max-age of that cookie:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", session.getId());
cookie.setMaxAge(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

Comment: On which cookie? I didn't create the cookie manually it is automatically created by the servlet.

Comment: Overwriting the cookie worked, thank you!

Comment: I'm having double cookie right now :/: I've got two cookies named: JSESSIONID

Comment: One that expires when the browser closes and one that I've set manually. However when I then restart the browser, only the one I set manually 'survives'. Is this bad that I've got double cookie?

Comment: The best answer in all the internet: simple and clean. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

when browser restarts some browser deletes cookies and that is why when after restart when you make new request server doesn't see cookie in request and treats it as a new session

Comment: Okay, but why does my github account stays logged in? Do they use something different?

Comment: Check your webapp's cookie and check github's cookie then restart browser and check both again

Comment: Hmm yeah it seems like it deletes the cookies. But how does facebook/google/github etc handle these problems?

Comment: login to google's account, see their cookie, and do a diff with your webapp's coookie, restart browser and compare them again